# How to setContentDescription to a RecylerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, accessibility

I'm changing my ListView to use a `RecylerView` and I would like to add a content description for each item. I would need to add that the listItem has the role of button, So it would read 'head' + 'desc' + "button".  I think I understand how to do that part but can't figure out where exactly to put it after a couple of tries. I've read some of the questions about this but a bit confused as to where I would put it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;

    // need to initialize variables above
    public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

        holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());


        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked " + listItem.getHead(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewHead;
        public TextView textViewDesc;
        public ImageView imageview;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
            //imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, view must be focusable in order to be parsed by accessibility tools.

Thus, you have to make the view be focusable. Also, you have to provide content description using [`View#setContentDescription(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)).

```
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        holder.itemView.setFocusable(true);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

        holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());

        holder.textViewHead.setContentDescription(listItem.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setContentDescription(listItem.getDesc());

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the button inside the ViewHolder in below code:-

```
 public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textViewHead;
    public TextView textViewDesc;
    public Button button;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
        textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    }
}
```

access this added button in onBindViewHolder like this:-

```
 holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
    holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());
 holder.button.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked " + listItem.getHead(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```